# how to find search word from google URL

Tags: java, url, google-search

I am searching a word (Rest call) in Google. I have three URLs for a single search.

1. Search in omni box (browser input box where we hit web address) shows URL as below.(my default search engine is Google)

   ```
   https://www.google.co.in/search?q=rest+call+in+java&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=BaaMVoLbHIKEuwT_oIQI
   ```
2. Search from Google home page shows URL as below.

   ```
   https://www.google.co.in/?gws_rd=ssl#q=rest%20call%20in%20java
   ```
3. Search from Google, but this time I am clicking Google logo from results page already shown in Google (it went to https://www.google.co.in/webhp?hl=en), after search in this google page it shows URL as below,

   ```
   https://www.google.co.in/webhp?hl=en#hl=en-IN&q=rest+call+in+java
   ```

All the above three urls shows the results same for the same query text, but three different URLs.

I want to get the word which was searched in Google textbox. How to get this word from Java.

I know if we using String regex, we can get, but there is three type of URLs for same search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of the URLs use same pattern for specifying the searched term, its under `q` query string. You can just use `String.indexOf` method and manipulate this pattern to get the searched term.

```
    //this is the url, it can be any of the 3 variants 
    String s = "https://www.google.co.in/search?q=rest+call+in+java&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=BaaMVoLbHIKEuwT_oIQI";

    //find the beginning of the searched term 
    int i = s.indexOf("q=");

    //find the end of the searched term
    int j = s.indexOf("&", i);
    j = j == -1 ? s.length() : j;

    //extract the searched term and decode
    String q = URLDecoder.decode(s.substring(i + 2, j));
```

As you mentioned another way is to use `regex`. You don't have to use separate `regex` for separate URLs. A single `regex` would do.

```
    //this is the url, it can be any of the 3 variants 
    String s = "https://www.google.co.in/search?q=rest+call+in+java&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=BaaMVoLbHIKEuwT_oIQI"; 

    //prepare the regex
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("q=(.*?)(?:&|$)");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);

    //extract and decode
    String q = matcher.find() ? URLDecoder.decode(matcher.group(1)) : "";
```